# Como fazer uma soma recursiva num objeto JSON em Angular 6?

Tags: angular, loop, recursão

Usando Angular 6, como poderia preencher o campo **total** que representa o número total de chefes direto e indireto de cada empregado?

Tenho os seguintes dados:

```
const employees = [
      {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'a',
        lastName: 'A',
        position: 'PA',
        chefes: [2, 3],
        compensation: '123.00'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        firstName: 'b',
        lastName: 'B',
        position: 'PB',
        chefes: [4],
        compensation: '456.00'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        firstName: 'c',
        lastName: 'C',
        position: 'PC',
        compensation: '789.00'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        firstName: 'd',
        lastName: 'D',
        position: 'PD',
        compensation: '1011.00'
      }
    ];
    return {employees};
```

No exemplo acima o empregado A tem como chefe direto  o empregado B e C. Mas o empregado B tem como chefe direto o empregado D. Ou seja somando chefes diretos + indiretos o empregado a possui 2+1=3 chefes o empregado B = 1 e os empregados C e D possuem 0 chefes.

Esse seria a parte do html que gera o nuero total de chefes (diretos + indiretos):

```
<dl>
  <dt>Título</dt>
  <dd>{{employee.position}}</dd>
  <dt>Compensation</dt>
  <dd>${{employee.compensation}}</dd>
  <dt>Total</dt>
  <dd>${{total????}}</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa... Dá pra fazer dessa forma:

```
  employees = [
    {
      id: 1,
      firstName: 'a',
      lastName: 'A',
      position: 'PA',
      chefes: [2, 3],
      compensation: '123.00'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      firstName: 'b',
      lastName: 'B',
      position: 'PB',
      chefes: [4],
      compensation: '456.00'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      firstName: 'c',
      lastName: 'C',
      position: 'PC',
      compensation: '789.00',
      chefes: []
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      firstName: 'd',
      lastName: 'D',
      position: 'PD',
      compensation: '1011.00',
      chefes: []
    }
  ];

  contaChefes(idInformado) {
    let totalChefes = 0;

    this.employees.map(e => {

      if (e.chefes && e.id === idInformado){
        totalChefes += e.chefes.length;

        e.chefes.forEach(r => {
          totalChefes += this.contaChefes(r);
        })
      }
    })
    return totalChefes;
  }

<dl>
    <dt>Título</dt>
    <dd>{{employee.position}}</dd>
    <dt>Compensation</dt>
    <dd>${{employee.compensation}}</dd>
    <dt>Total</dt>
    <dd> {{ contaChefes(employee.id) }} </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Neste caso e melhor usar reduce que map.